# Dual boot caused problem with FIRST monitor (not second) on Linux Mint Cinnamon, need to recover files from the partition

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, data-recovery, multi-monitor

I need to recover some files from an office computer where I installed Windows 10 + Linux Mint, but the only monitor I have access to isn't recognized by the OS.

Back around 2018/2019, I had two monitors on a new computer and, when I installed dual boot Mint-Win10, Linux Mint did for some God forsaken reason recognise the second monitor as the first one. I didn't have luck trying to fix it but since it technically worked I didn't pay mind to it. When I got relocated and lost access to my second monitor, Linux Mint stopped showing the login screen (I assume it was still trying to display it on a first monitor that wasn't there*). I couldn't fix it because every problem/solution I found was about the first monitor working and the second one having a problem. Still, I could just hit enter, write the password, enter again and after a while it picked the monitor properly. I wasn't needing Linux that much anyways.

Eventually I stopped using Linux Mint on that computer altogether, opting instead for WSL (I can run everything I need like that, while I have no easy way to run everything I need for my job on Linux). Now I have a bunch of experimental results I need to recover and, when I tried to enter my password the same way I always did, it didn't show anything. I can hit ctrl+alt+F1 and visualize the command line but when I run xrandr it says "can't open display". Most of the solutions I found online assume I either have a first monitor properly configured or that the error happens when connecting to a server, but none of those are relevant to me.

Is there any way to force Linux to recognise a monitor it detects (otherwise I wouldn't be able to see the command line)?

*I'm guessing it could an issue with the type of connector since my old second monitor (smaller) had an HDMI cable and was connected to the HDMI port while the first one (the one I still have) has a VGA cable connected to a DVI-I dual link port with an adaptor. I have time and I'm very short on money so I'd rather not try to solve it by buying a new cable.

Comment: Can you not afford $5 - $10 US to convert the [DVI to HDMI](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dvi-to-hdmi+adapter&hvadid=177351899671&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9028644&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=7955927907706864385&hvtargid=kwd-6922966181&hydadcr=18889_9696644&tag=googhydr-20&ref=pd_sl_954s2joebw_e) or even [VGA to HDMI](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=vga+to+hdmi&crid=86YIDXB3HPMH&sprefix=vga+to+hdmi%2Caps%2C140&ref=nb_sb_noss_1).  Spending $10 up front is going to save you time and effort.  Note that these aren't cables.

Comment: As a second option, is the monitor recognized by any of the Plethora of distributions besides mint that are on a Live CD/USB, or even a Mint LiveCD? And were both monitors connected to the same Graphics Card?  This might be as simple as a motherboard jumper reset for the Firmware/BIOS

Comment: Both monitors were connected to the same graphics card which has 4 different ports. The secondary monitor was connected to the HDMI port while the primary was connected to the DVI port.

I'll try to get ahold of converters or an USB stick I can burn. I have time and effort because I'm about to be out of a job so I'd rather not buy hardware. I'm from a third world country and I'd rather save 5-10 USD if I can. 

All I need is to extract some files. I could borrow an external disk to try to take the files out but the system won't recognise it when trying to open it via Ctrl+Alt+F1 terminal.

Comment: Then connect the Secondary monitor to the DVI port  You'll need an HDMI to DVI converter,  I believe the other option is to reset the PEG (PCI Express Graphics) setting, but that's in the firmware settings, which you can't see.  The PEG is most likely currently set to DVI.  Resetting the firmware/BOS should put it on internal, or auto